# Trying to read back depth from an FBO using glReadPixels fails on an AMD card

Tags: opengl, fbo

I have a problem reading back the depth values from an FBO on an AMD Radeon 7750 (driver Catalyst 13.12) The code works on all nVidia cards I've tried (Main rig has a GTX 680 running driver 332.21) but I know that AMD are generally a little more picky with the details when it comes to OpenGL specification conformance. Both machines run Windows 7.

The code is in Delphi but should be very straightforward to port to any other language. (I tried porting to C++ but the glut I found didn't allow me to create core profile context.)

```
procedure TForm2.Button_CombinedWithDepthClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  VFBOId: Cardinal;
  VFBOSTatus: Cardinal;
  VErrString: string;
  VCol0TexId: Cardinal;
  VDepthRenderBufferId: Cardinal;
  VR16UIColorVals: array of Word;
  VRGBA32FColorVals: array of Single;
  VDepthValsFloats: array of Single;
  VDepthValsInt32s: array of Integer;
  VDepthValsUInt32s: array of Cardinal;
  VDepthValsUInt16s: array of Word;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Init and setup FBO
  glGenFramebuffers(1, @VFBOId);

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, VFBOId);

  glGenTextures(1, @VCol0TexId);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VCol0TexId);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  if CheckBox_R16UI.Checked then
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16UI, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nil)
  else
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nil);
  glFrameBufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, VCol0TexId, 0);

  glGenRenderbuffers(1, @VDepthRenderBufferId);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, VDepthRenderBufferId);
  glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, VDepthRenderBufferId);

  VFBOstatus := glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
  if VFBOstatus <> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE then
  begin
    if VFBOstatus = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT then
      VErrString := 'FBO Error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT'
    else if VFBOstatus = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED then
      VErrString := 'FBO Error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED'
    else if VFBOStatus = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER then
      VErrString := 'FBO Error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER'
    else if VFBOStatus = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER then
      VErrString := 'FBO Error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER'
    else if VFBOStatus = GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT then
      VErrString := 'FBO Error: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT';
    raise Exception.Create(VErrString);
  end;

  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

  //Clear color
  if CheckBox_R16UI.Checked then
  begin
    glClearColorIuiEXT(590, 200, 314, 147);
    glClearDepth(0.69);
  end
  else
  begin
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625);
    glClearDepth(0.27);
  end;
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //Read back
  GlError;
  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
  if CheckBox_R16UI.Checked then
  begin
    SetLength(VR16UIColorVals, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height);
    for i := 0 to High(VR16UIColorVals) do
      VR16UIColorVals[i] := 123;
    glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, @VR16UIColorVals[0]);
  end
  else
  begin
    SetLength(VRGBA32FColorVals, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height * 4);
    for i := 0 to High(VRGBA32FColorVals) do
      VRGBA32FColorVals[i] := 0.3;
    glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, @VRGBA32FColorVals[0]);
  end;
  GlError;

  SetLength(VDepthValsFloats, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height);
  for i := 0 to High(VDepthValsFloats) do
    VDepthValsFloats[i] := 123.074;
  glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, @VDepthValsFloats[0]);
  GlError;

  SetLength(VDepthValsInt32s, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height);
  for i := 0 to High(VDepthValsInt32s) do
    VDepthValsInt32s[i] := 456;
  glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_INT, @VDepthValsInt32s[0]);
  GlError;

  SetLength(VDepthValsUInt32s, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height);
  for i := 0 to High(VDepthValsUInt32s) do
    VDepthValsUInt32s[i] := 2378;
  glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, @VDepthValsUInt32s[0]);
  GlError;

  SetLength(VDepthValsUInt16s, Panel_1.Width * Panel_1.Height);
  for i := 0 to High(VDepthValsUInt16s) do
    VDepthValsUInt16s[i] := 961;
  glReadPixels(0, 0, Panel_1.Width, Panel_1.Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, @VDepthValsUInt16s[0]);
  GlError;

  glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

  SetLength(VDepthValsFloats, 0);
  SetLength(VDepthValsInt32s, 0);
  SetLength(VDepthValsUInt16s, 0);
  SetLength(VDepthValsUInt32s, 0);

  // Clean up
  glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, @VDepthRenderBufferId);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glDeleteTextures(1, @VCol0TexId);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
  glDeleteFramebuffers(1, @VFBOId);
end;
```

The switch is a checkbox and the only thing not included here is the creation of an OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile context with debug flag and debug callback function defined. On the nVidia card both code paths works fine, the depth values read from the FBO when an R16UI color buffer is bound to COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 are correct. Both cards works when an RGBA32F color buffer is bound to the FBO's COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 but the AMD Radeon 7750 fails when trying to read depth, having the glReadPixels call cause a OpenGL error.

The OpenGL Debug callback provides some additional information on the error:

> Debug Output: OpenGLDebugCallback. Source: SOURCE_API  Type:
>   TYPE_ERROR  Severity: SEVERITY_HIGH  Message: 'glReadPixels has failed
>   because the operation requires that both source and destination
>   internal format must share the same numeric type (integer,
>   single-precision float or double-precision float)
>   (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)' Process ReadDepthSimple.exe

I can't find this as a valid cause for a GL_INVALID_OPERATION on the glReadPixels page. If I comment out the line for attaching the depth buffer the behaviour on the nVidia card in both cases and the AMD card in the case of color attachment RGBA32F gives

> Debug Output: OpenGLDebugCallback. Source: SOURCE_API  Type:
>   TYPE_ERROR  Severity: SEVERITY_HIGH  Message: 'GL_INVALID_OPERATION
>   error generated. Drawable does not have depth buffer.' Process
>   ReadDepthSimple.exe

However, when using a R16UI color buffer on the AMD card I get the same error before, the complaint about different datatypes.

I like to point to the "Driver bug!" sign on the wall but maybe I've done something wrong. I need this to work somehow, to render to an R16UI color attachment and depth and reading both of them back.

Any ideas? Can anyone else get reading depth to work on an AMD card using an FBO with a R16UI color buffer attached?

Comment: Have you tried creating the render buffer storage using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` instead of `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8`? Or (if you need the stencil buffer) try reading it back using `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8`

Comment: @GuyRT: Using `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` as renderbuffer format, attaching it to the FBO's `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` and reading it back using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8` gives good values in the 24 bits of that uint 32 array containing the read back depth buffer in the same way as before: works with an RGBA32F color buffer bound but causes the same `GL_INVALID_OPERAION (...must share the same numeric format...)` error with a R16UI bound.

Renderbuffer format `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` attached only to depth and readpixels type `GL_FLOAT` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`: ok for `RGBA32F `and error for `R16UI`.

Comment: @Andon: Thanks! You set me on the right path with the `glReadBuffer` comment. When reading from the depth with an FBO bound it works on both my cards when calling `glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);` before. I will look at the note in your second comment tomorrow.

Comment: You should probably be using the format: `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL` and type: `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8` when you try to read your packed depth+stencil buffer with `glReadPixels (...)` given your RBO setup. Let me know if using that changes the outcome any. That, or do not attach a packed depth+stencil RBO to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`.

Comment: I've tried around with quite a few different renderbuffer/FBO configurations and they all give the same behaviour on the AMD card: not allowed to read the depth due to mismatching numeric format. Setting the `glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)` before reading depth and it works.

Comment: ^ Confirm, setting `glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)` makes it work on Nvidia card.  Thank.